# JavaFX Rotating NumberAxis independently

Tags: java, javafx, yaxis

I am trying to create an axis system like that:
[image: Axises]

I am using the javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis.

The x axis is pretty straight forward:

```
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(xStart,xEnd,xIncrement);
```

Is there a way to rotate the y axis by 90 degrees so that it looks like the above picture?

I tried to use setRotate of Node but, as the documentation says, it rotates the whole graphic. (I want to rotate only the axis not the numbers that come with that).

```
 NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(yStart,yEnd,yIncrement);
 yAxis.setRotate(90);
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you post an example and explain how it is behaving differently to the way you want it to behave?

Comment: @James_D You are right, I rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the side:

```
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(yStart,yEnd,yIncrement);
yAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT); // or Side.RIGHT
```

Here is a quick example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AxisTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        NumberAxis leftAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);
        leftAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT);

        NumberAxis bottomAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);


        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Pane center = new Pane();
        center.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        root.add(center, 1, 0);
        root.add(leftAxis, 0, 0);
        root.add(bottomAxis, 1, 1);

        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]